# Basic Authentication problem with custom API endpoints

Tags: customization

I have problem with basic authentication when using custom API custom end point, can anyone help me out for how to set up basic authentication for custom API endpoint. Also I want to get user id of logged in user when I use my custom API.

Comment: What have you tried? What *exact* problem are you having? Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/246215/edit) with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at actual "basic authentication", check out the [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) plugin. Note that it's for the REST API plugin, not the core implementation, so you'll need to adjust some filters.

If you're looking for authentiction for the current user based on their current cookies in the browser, the REST API has that built in, you'll just need to pass a `X-WP-Nonce` header with your HTTP request.

You can learn more here: http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should add permission_callback parameter when registering a custom route

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function ($data) {
        register_rest_route('wp/v1', '/hamza', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_posts',
                'permission_callback' => function ($request) {
                        if (current_user_can('edit_others_posts'))
                        return true;
                 }
             )
        );
    });
```